# Spring's ResourcePatternResolver.getResources() very slow with large file-sets

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot/Batch app that processes about 30K files.  The processing of the files is done by reading in each file, parsing it using various regular expressions, and saving bits of the file to a database.  It's pretty slick and can process all 30K files in about 1 hour -- EXCEPT for app-initialization, which takes an extra hour of it's own!

In my Batch code I am setting up a partitioning-step and setting it's resources based on a subset of files that they themselves match a simple regular expression.  It is the obtaining of these resources that seems to be the performance killer: if I have a small handful of files then app startup is just seconds -- however, if I have 30K files then app startup takes about one hour!

Take this code:

```
@Autowired
org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver resolver;

String pattern = "file:/project_root/subfolder_*/logfile_*";
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources(pattern);
```

When I run the above using 2 subfolders, each containing a small handful of files (say, about 6), the app spins-up and executes in pretty short order.

However, if I throw 15K files into each of the 2 subfolders, the app takes about an hour just to initialize!  It takes about another hour to process all the files -- but that's totally expected, due to all the processing involved.

For example, upon starting the app with 30K files the last few lines in my log are these:

```
2014-12-30 13:53:10.284  INFO 1268 [main] --- o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2014-12-30 13:53:11.152  INFO 1268 [main] --- o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=CasLogFileToDb_Job_2014-12-30T13:52:49.792-0700]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2014-12-30 13:53:12.706  INFO 1268 [main] --- o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [CasLogFileToDb_PartitioningStep_2014-12-30T13:52:49.797-0700]
2014-12-30 15:17:59.020  INFO 1268 [taskExecutor-6] --- o.u.c.c.processor.WorkflowManager        : Starting to process file (/common/logs/cas/brandon-temp/test-prodback/cas1/catalina.out-20130626-131501.gz)
```

The app then just sits there for about an hour at "Executing Step", after which it then starts at "Starting to process file" -- the first 3 lines of the log are Spring-Batch, the last line is my code right before it actually starts to process a file.

The question is: why is it taking an hour just to getResources() ?
Anyone use getResources() with a similar large set of files and have dramatically speedier performance?  Is there another way to get a subset of files like this, but that might execute much faster?

---

Incidentally, listing the files similarly from the command-line takes about 10 seconds.
ie:

```
ls -al project_root/subfolder_*/logfile_*
```

---

## UPDATE #1:

Following the suggestion from Michael, I spent a bit of time profiling this area of the code to determine if it appeared to be the same source he linked to.  It appears to be so.

I staged about 3K files into my test environment (not the full 30K worth).  Then I placed a breakpoint at the start of @BeforeJob and then at the start of my code that begins to process the files... and then started and stopped the profiler at those 2 points... IOW: the profiler captured everything happening between job-start and an individual task-start.

Here are the results:

[image]

From what I'm getting out of that, the top 2 CPU-hogs are a MySQL-call a SpringBatch-call.  This is all before any of my code has a chance to do any DB-calls, or even actually read a file.

So, it sounds like it is the situation described in the link provided by Michael.
The mysterious part is, I am using Spring Boot 1.1.9.RELEASE which in turn is using Spring Batch 3.0.2.RELEASE -- and the link provided by Michael stated that this bug was fixed in Spring Batch 2.2.0.

Upgrading my Boot project to the latest release (1.2.0.RELEASE) had no discernible effect.

---

## UPDATE #2:

To answer Michael's question about what things I have that are Step-scoped... I have 3 @StepScope methods.  The first two implement Batch's ItemReader and ItemWriter.  The 3rd one is my.WorkflowManager, which implements Batch's CompletionPolicy and is responsible for monitoring an individual file's processing-progression (ie: keeps track of progress-data, moves files once they are done being processed, holds state from the reader to communicate back to Batch once the file is done being read, etc).

```
@StepScope
@Bean
ItemReader reader(WorkflowManager workflowManager);

@StepScope
@Bean
ItemWriter writer(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate);

@StepScope
@Bean
public WorkflowManager workflowManager(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String gzipResourceLocation) {
    return new WorkflowManager(gzipResourceLocation);
}
```

---

## UPDATE #3:

This is the WorkflowManager(condensed):

```
public class WorkflowManager implements CompletionPolicy, MyFileManager {

   public WorkflowManager(  String pathToFileGzip,
                            String pathToStagingFolder,
                            String pathToArchiveFolder) {

    this.fileGzip = ResourceUtils.getFile(pathToFileGzip.trim()).toPath();
    this.pathToStagingFolder = ResourceUtils.getFile(pathToStagingFolder.trim()).toPath();
    this.pathToArchiveFolder = ResourceUtils.getFile(pathToArchiveFolder.trim()).toPath();
   }

   @BeforeStep
   public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution);

   @AfterStep
   public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution);

   @Override
   public void readingIsComplete();

   @Override
   public boolean isReadingComplete();

   @Override
   public boolean isComplete(RepeatContext context, RepeatStatus status);

   @Override
   public boolean isComplete(RepeatContext context);

   @Override
   public RepeatContext start(RepeatContext parent);

   @Override
   public void update(RepeatContext context);

   @Override
   public BufferedReader getFileAsBufferedReader();

}
```

Comment: What you are describing sounds similar to the issue we fixed a while back here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1908.  That being said, are you *sure* the call to that line is what is causing the issue?  Have you profiled it at all?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I believe it is the issue you have linked to; please see my lengthy update, above.  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: `StepScope.get` being the batch call...what is Step Scoped that you're retrieving?  That wasn't the batch call I was expecting...

Comment: @MichaelMinella please see my update #2.  And THANK YOU for persisting in looking at this for me!  :)

Comment: So what is happening in that WorkflowManager constructor?  Can we see that code?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Update #3 is included.  Obviously there's more in the constructor but it's just logging and sanity-check type stuff (ie: null-checks, simple stuff like that).  Also, all of these methods are actually implemented, they aren't abstract.

Comment: So when that constructor is called, you're creating `File` handles for a file and two directories.  So with your 30k files, you're creating 90k new `File` references just to get their full paths.  Just humor me and what happens if you just set the values in the `WorkflowManager` to the strings passed in?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Been out of the office as well as tied up on other projects; I'll answer back at you as soon as I can; sorry for the delay, but I do appreciate the help.